# How many clock cycles

Tags: cpu

Actually it differs from CPU to CPU but it is possible to choose a mainstream CPU technology used in moderate servers or home computers.

How many clock cycles it takes to read a file of 50KB from Ethernet socket and then resend this file to another IP address without saving the file to disk? I assume this operation can be done on RAM. If not, how many clock cycles required if a copy of this 50Kb file is to be stored into the disk (7200 rpm)?

Thank you.

Comment: No way to tell. The Ethernet card has it's own circuitry, higher-end cards even offload some of the TCP/IP handling, they place data in the card's buffers and interrupt the CPU to pick it up (who knows what the CPU is doing, and what time it takes to go around to service the card's interrupt); it might even transfer data directly to RAM. If you mix in a disk, with it's own *completely unrelated* delays, all bets are off.

Comment: @vonbrand Thank you. So the Ethernet card has its own buffer. Does Ethernet card pulls and uploads data from/to the net without using CPU resources -only interrupting CPU when buffer is full? Is data from the buffer transferred to RAM over the CPU or directly?

Comment: "Does Ethernet card pulls and uploads data from/to the net without using CPU resources" – That depends on the card. "only interrupting CPU when buffer is full" – That depends on the card, the driver, the OS, and possibly user settings. "Is data from the buffer transferred to RAM over the CPU or directly?" – That depends on the computer architecture, the CPU, the card, the driver, the OS, and possibly user settings.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the answer. So it is possible not to occupy CPU while filling the buffer and while transferring data to RAM. I suppose most mainstream hardware and OS takes advantage of this. It seems to be a high probability that most commercial servers are designed that way.

Comment: This question is a cross between computer hardware and operating systems, and seems to heavily depend on the particular hardware setup. As such, it doesn't seem a good fit for this site, unless somebody steps us to give an overview on how one would measure the number of clock cycles in your scenarios.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus You are right that the answer to this question depends on hardware. I thought there would be an optimum approach adopted by most hardware manufacturers and someone would answer according to that mainstream/common solution.